# How to get post attachments in gallery post format template

Tags: gallery, post-formats

I'm doing a WordPress theme, and I get stuck on one thing. As you know, the post-format in WordPress has different types of formats, I did all the types except the gallery slideshow.  What I need, for example I had create one new post, and added gallery with pictures to this post, then I chose a gallery in post format.  The problem, the gallery shows me all the images included in WordPress but I want to show only the post images.

**Code**:

```
    if ( ! function_exists(    'flexi_gallery_slideshow' ) ) :
   /**
   * Display an optional post images.   slideshow
   *
   */ 
  function flexi_gallery_slideshow( ){

  echo '<ul class="bxslider" >';
  $args = array(
  'post_parent' =>$post->ID,
  'post_type' => 'attachment',
  'orderby' => 'menu_order', // you can   also sort images by date or be name
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'numberposts' => 3, // number of. images (slides)
  'post_mime_type' => 'image'
  );
   if ( $images = get_children( $args )  ) {
   foreach( $images as $image ) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, array('640', '400')        );

            echo '</li>';
        }
  }

    echo '</ul>';

 }
 endif;
```

Comment: Where and how do you call the function? Had you checked that `$post` holds sane value at that point?

Comment: i create new content-gallery file and call the function there, and i create a post in gallery format, and i chose some pictures as galleries, the out of slider is shown the pictures inside the media not shown the pictures which i loaded, shown all the pictures in media

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had sort out this with function get_post_gallery

find the answer

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'flexi_gallery_slideshow' ) ) :
/**
* Display an optional post read more link
*
*/ 
function flexi_gallery_slideshow( ) {
echo '<ul class="bxslider">';
if ( get_post_gallery() ) :
        $gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );

        /* Loop through all the image and output them one by one */
        foreach( $gallery['src'] as $src ) : ?>
          <li> <img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" class="gallery-slider" alt="Gallery image" /> </li>
          <?php
        endforeach;
    endif;
echo '</ul>'  ;     
}
endif;
```