# Generate links on all images in posts - is there a hook?

Tags: images, hooks, media

I am looking for a way to replace all links on images.
Currently when a user clicks an image it links to the source file.

What I want it to do is to ink to: example.com/editor=12&image=filename.jpg
So every  that encloses an  should link to that site with the image filename so it can be loaded in an editor.

First, I tried to replace the links with ajax, but that does not work with lazy load and also seems less practical.
The second thing I tried is to filter the $content of the post. But with that I can only replace the /wp-content/uploads/ part. 
I can’t filter for the first part (http://) which leads to also all src being replaced and no image shows up at all.

Is there any way to do this by hooks maybe?

Kind regards 
Patrick

Update: So this works for images added as single image, however it seems not to work on gallery shortcode even if the priority is 12 and short-codes are already executed.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_content_filter', 12);
function my_content_filter($content) {

if ( is_single() )

   $content = str_replace('<a href="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/','<a href="https://example.com/?editor=82&image=',$content);
  return $content;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the [`wp_get_attachment_url`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) or `wp_get_attachment_image_src` filter?

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a similar problem, so found a possible solution.

The issue is the 'inline' images, as opposed to images that are attachments (like a gallery), is that there is no filter for `the_content()` that deals specifically with the images tag. (At least, I haven't found it yet.)

So, you need to use some regex to search `the_content()` for the image tag, and get each image into an array, then you can loop through the image array as you need.

I found this code here: https://gist.github.com/jlord/3680879 . I have not tested it, but it may give you a start:

```
 // get the content from the post
  $posttext = $post->post_content;
  // next line added to process any shortcodes in the content string
  $posttext = do_shortcode($posttext);
  // make a variable for the string you're looking to find in all of the content
  $regex = '~<img [^\>]*\ />~';
  // find the first things inside of the second thing and put them inside of the third thing
  preg_match_all($regex, $posttext, $images);
  // redefine posttext as itself minus all the things you found 
  $posttext = preg_replace($regex, '', $posttext);

  // now posttext has no images, and $images is an array of image tags
  // have fun, o lord of jellies ?> <!-- this part is from issac -->

<div id="thePostText">
  <?php 
  // now spit out all the text
  echo $posttext; ?>
</div>

<div id='thePostImages'>
  <?php 
  // for each image, wrap it in the p tags and spit it out 
  foreach ( $images[0] as $image ) {
  echo '<p class="aPostImage">' . $image . '</p>'; } ?>
</div>
```

You would place this code in a template, inside The Loop. Then use that template for the post output.

I'd be interested if this helps. It may save you a couple of hours on the googles, which is how I found it.

**Added**

Since the   `$posttext = $post->post_content;` is not using `the_content()` (which also processes shortcodes), then shortcodes in the post content may not be processed. In particular, the `[gallery]` shortcode is not processed. I suspect other shortcodes are also not processed.

So I added an additional line to the above code:

```
$posttext = do_shortcode($posttext);
```

to get shortcodes processed in the content string.

**Added**

The above code doesn't necessarily allow you to hook into the output of gallery images. So I found this code here, which can be used as a starting point: [How to get post attachments in gallery post format template](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/227935/how-to-get-post-attachments-in-gallery-post-format-template)

```
if ( get_post_gallery() ) :
        $gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );

        /* Loop through all the image and output them one by one */
        foreach( $gallery['src'] as $src ) : ?>
          <li> <img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" class="gallery-slider" alt="Gallery image" /> </li>
          <?php
        endforeach;
    endif;
```

Note that all of the above are  code snippets, not an end-to-end solution. But they may be helpful to put together a solution that meets your needs.

Comment: Hey Rick, thank you very much, that actually could help a lot! :) I will play around with this a little and will report back in a few days :)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me, it has the same effect as 
`$content = str_replace('<a href="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/','<a href="https://example.com?editor=82&image=',$content);` it does not find any strings at all, however this works (bit it will also replace urls in <img> tag:
`$content = str_replace('/wp-content/uploads/','<a /?editor=82&image=',$content);` Kind of strange if you ask me, as if the tags are added way later...

Comment: I was just about to post, that it works with normal images but not with shortcodes :D let me fiddle arround with this  a little, thanks!

Comment: do_shortcode seems not to help, i might be wrong, but it does not seem to execute the shortcodes but filter them out -> returns (string) Content with shortcodes filtered out.

**edit** ok, it actually should do the shortcoes... but thats also the case if i give it the priority 12 because the shortcodes run at 11... i dont get i O_o

Comment: For images as attachments, try the code here as a starting point: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63980/wordpress-gallery-post-gallery-filter-doesnt-work-with-feeds .

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why, but this works for gallery as well :D
@Rick Hellewell, thank you very much for your help on this topic!

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_content_filter', 12);

function my_content_filter($content) {

    global $post;

    if ( is_single() ) {

        // For gallery
        $content = str_replace("<a href='https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/","<a href='https://example.com/?editor=82&image=",$content);

        $content = str_replace('<a href="https://example.com//wp-content/uploads/','<a href="https://example.com/?editor=82&image=',$content);


    }

    return $content;

}
```